# Plugable Varistor and Fuse Cartridge for easy and safe replacement

Tags: circuit-protection, fuses, over-voltage-protection, replacement, varistor

As I have concluded with some tests, by reading some posts and even asking a question on this forum, Varistors can get damaged with multiple or even just one cycle of use. They fail as a short, being useful to protect for additional surges, but not allowing the protected circuit to get powered, therefore requiring maintenance to get the circuit working again (appliance disassembly, de-soldering the old varistor and re-soldering a new one), which can be quite complicated maintenance, especially for someone who has no knowledge of electricity.

Therefore, I wanted to attempt to solve this problem by providing a kind of external cartridge with a Varistor (and perhaps also a fuse).

I realise UK plugs normally have a fuse inside so that you can replace the fuse without disassemblying the appliance. However, Schuko and IEC plugs have no such thing. Furthermore, the project I'm trying to build sits on an electrical pannel, with Din-rail mounting, so it doesn't really have a plug. So I was looking to do something similar to the UK plugs, but so that it's even easier to replace the fuse and Varistor without requiring appliance disassembly.

I was looking for a way to have an external cartridge with a Varistor and a Fuse that could be easily unplugged and plugged to replace those components and that has no external metal parts that are live, so that they could be replaced even by child, being sure they wouldn't get hurt by electricity, similar to a plug and a socket. The cartridge should be plugged into the appliance chassis on the outside, so that it requires no disassembly to replace. My first idea was to have a power socket (Shucko, IEC...) mounted to the appliance chassis and the appropiate plug with a Varistor inside. Having more plugs with Varistors available (as cartridges), would allow easy and quick replace of the Varistor, involving only unplugging a power plug and plugging in a new one. This job can easily be done by someone with no knowledge of electricity because it is as dangerous as plugging an appliance into the wall. However, this obviously doesn't make much sense to have a visibly identifiable socket that is not really a power outlet, and it can be confusing.

My question is: Is there any plugable (socket and plug) pair that is not strictly associated with a mains voltage outlet and can be used for this matter without creating the false impression that it is a power outlet when it really is not? I'm looking for something that can be easily unplugged and plugged back in without any risk of injury (without exposed metal parts) just like mains voltage plugs but that thing should NOT be mains voltage plugs.

Comment: I would say, don't use an MOV; use an alternative.

Comment: Exactly what product lifetime are you looking for? Surge frequency in typical locations is such that, even a fairly small MOV is sufficient for 10 year product lifetimes. Poor MOVs: they get such a bad rap because they fail in dramatic fashion *long after* having provided reliable service until the fatal blow(s).

Comment: @Andyaka What alternative would you suggest?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, you are correct, they might withstand several but I just wanted to make sure the Varistor is not a "single point of failure".

Comment: You can get TVS diodes that are a more reliable alternative. Yes, you still have to protect them with a fuse but, the TVS diode doesn't suffer from degradation (unlike the flaky MOV). Not as cheap as an MOV but looking good I would say. And, if you were careful in the design you could use a GDT/TVS combination that could avoid a fuse.

Comment: @Andyaka I should have mentioned that the circuit that I'm trying to protect from Overvoltage is a mains voltage circuit. Would a TVS still be suitable for that? I'm asking this because I've never seen a TVS on a mains voltage circuit, I only see them on low voltage circuitry. On mains, I always see Varistors. What are the trade-offs btw?

Comment: I think you should revisit your earlier question and accept the appropriate answer before we go further forward @Dinis

Comment: @Andyaka What would be the DT/TVS combination that could avoid a fuse? How are they connected with respect to each other and the mains voltage L and N and why do they avoid a fuse?

Comment: (I meant "GDT/TVS" on my last comment, not "DT/TVS")